# Which scripting language and web server to use for mulltithreading

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, server-side, serversocket, scripting-language

I am new to web programming

I need to develop a web page running on a server, that needs to show progress status of 10 threads simultaneously. Also I would require SQLite database integration.

Please tell me what are the options available for me for choosing a scripting language and web server [socket] development framework. 
Also suggest the most suitable.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are exactly your threads? Are they programs written in a sepecific language? This is essential since the webpage has to communicate with them

Comment: The threads are socket based network programs written in java. They essentially establish a connection with a client and transfer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python](http://docs.python.org/index.html) would be an excellent choice. It has SQLite integrated as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Python also has the following features (and many others) integrated:

- threading and synchronization
- Networking (sockets)
- lots of web server (and web pages, etc) handling options

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) is a page that discusses several different Python web server frameworks. Im not very familiar with it, but Ive heard lots of good things about Django.

Another excellent choice would be [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/). Ruby is the scripting language and Rails is the Web Server Framework.